# How can we select filtered values/records from one single table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an inline Table-valued Function

```
[dbo].[Sales] (@FromDate DATE, @ToDate DATE) T1
```

that returns a table:

```
+----------+----------+-----+
| Location | Category |Sales|
+----------+----------+-----+
| AMB      | A        | 10  |
| BWD      | A        | 20  |
| UNR      | A        | 30  |
| BWD      | C        | 40  |
| BWD      | P        | 50  |
| BWD      | S        | 60  |
| BWD      | W        | 70  |
+----------+----------+-----+
```

Now, I wish to apply certain filters on this output and get 6 values in a single row.
The **logic** behind the SELECT is:

```
    SELECT
            (SELECT SUM(T1.Sales) WHERE T1.Category = 'P') AS 'Pipes',
            (SELECT SUM(T1.Sales) WHERE T1.Category = 'C') AS 'Casing',
            (SELECT SUM(T1.Sales) WHERE T1.Category = 'W') AS 'Wires',
            (SELECT SUM(T1.Sales) WHERE T1.Location = 'BWD' AND T1.Category IN ('A','S')) AS 'Switches',
            (SELECT SUM(T1.Sales) WHERE T1.Location IN ('AMB','UNR')) AS 'Accessories',
            (SUM(T1.Sales)) AS 'Total'

    FROM [dbo].[Sales] (@FromDate,@ToDate) T1
```

with the desired result being:

```
+-------+--------+-------+----------+-------------+-------+
| Pipes | Casing | Wires | Switches | Accessories | Total |
+-------+--------+-------+----------+-------------+-------+
|    50 |     40 |    70 |       80 |          40 |   280 |
+-------+--------+-------+----------+-------------+-------+
```

I know the SELECT query I wrote is wrong. How can I get this desired output in one single query without calling the function repeatedly? I want this to be as fast as possible. (Any alternatives are welcome!)

Next Step:
Once I get these 6 values in one row using a single SELECT, I wish to return these 6 values as part of another TVF (an outer TVF).

**I am a beginner and I would really appreciate if you could give your honest advice/opinion about the speed/performance aspects about this query or a better alternative (if any)**.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If this is SQL Server, why do I see `MySQL` tag in your question???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation, not subqueries:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Category = 'P' THEN T1.Sales END) as Pipes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Category = 'C' THEN T1.Sales END) as Casing,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Category = 'W' THEN T1.Sales END) as Wires,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Location = 'BWD' AND T1.Category IN ('A','S') THEN T1.Sales END) as Switches,
       SUM(CASE WHEN T1.Location IN ('AMB', 'UNR') THEN T1.Sales END) AS Accessories,
       SUM(T1.Sales) AS Total
FROM [dbo].[Sales] (@FromDate, @ToDate) T1;
```

Notice that I also removed the single quotes around the column aliases.  That is a bad habit.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.